# sqlalchemy foreign key relationship attributes

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a User table and a Friend table.  The Friend table holds two foreign keys both to my User table as well as a status field.  I am trying to be able to call attributes from my User table on a Friend object. For example, I would love to be able to do something like, friend.name, or friend.email.

```
class User(Base):
    """ Holds user info """

    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(25), unique=True)
    email = Column(String(50), unique=True)
    password = Column(String(25))
    admin = Column(Boolean)

    # relationships
    friends = relationship('Friend', backref='Friend.friend_id',primaryjoin='User.id==Friend.user_id', lazy='dynamic')

class Friend(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'friend'

    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(User.id), primary_key=True)
    friend_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(User.id), primary_key=True)
    request_status = Column(Boolean)
```

When I get `friend` objects all I have is the 2 `user_ids` and i want to display all properties of each user so I can use that information in forms, etc.  I am new to sqlalchemy - still trying to learn more advanced features.  This is just a snippet from a larger Flask project and this feature is going to be for `friend` requests, etc.  I've tried to look up association objects, etc, but I am having a hard with it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

First, if you're using `flask-sqlalchemy`, why are you using directly sqlalchemy instead of the Flask's `db.Model`?

I strongly reccomend to use [`flask-sqlalchemy`](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/) extension since it leverages the sessions and some other neat things.

Creating a proxy convenience object is straightforward. Just add the relationship with it in the `Friend` class.

```
class Friend(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'friend'

    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(User.id), primary_key=True)
    friend_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(User.id), primary_key=True)
    request_status = Column(Boolean)

    user = relationship('User', foreign_keys='Friend.user_id')
    friend = relationship('User', foreign_keys='Friend.friend_id')
```

SQLAlchemy will take care of the rest and you can access the user object simply by:

```
name = friend.user.name
```

If you plan to use the `user` object every time you use the `friend` object specify  `lazy='joined'` in the `relationship`. This way it loads both object in a single query.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm getting: sqlalchemy.exc.AmbiguousForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship Friend.user - there are multiple foreign key paths linking the tables.  Specify the 'foreign_keys' argument, providing a list of those columns which should be counted as containing a foreign key reference to the parent table. This is the problem I was facing because the Friend object has 2 foreignkeys both to User.id. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Ptrkcon oh sorry i didn't get the point. i fixed my answer adding the `foreign_keys` argument. I tried here and it worked :)

Comment: Perfect! I was thinking about it much to hard. Its always the simple answers that work best! I'm new to this stuff and didn't realize you can have foreign_keys references the table its in. Thank you

Comment: This is confusing: why do you need the relationship on the Friend? Shouldn't the backref on the friends on User take care of it? It feels like duplication

Comment: @Tjorriemorrie Yeah, as I said in the answer, you just need the `Friend` relationships. OP asked how to access both users linked. You should place a `backref` on the `Friend` relationship to enhance `User` providing a `friends`. Hope this answers. :)

Comment: Thanks, the equivalent in my relationships of `foreign_keys='Friend.user_id'` was what I really needed since the docs don't actually specify linking between classes (most examples just have 1 class, which is sometimes annoying)