# Many-to-many, self-referential, non-symmetrical relationship (twitter model) via Association Object in SqlAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, many-to-many, relationship

How would one best implement a many-to-many, self-referential, non symmetrical relationship (think Twitter) in SqlAlchemy? I want to use an association object (let's call this class "Follow") so that I can have additional attributes associated with the relationship.

I've seen plenty of examples which use an association tables, but none like I've describe above. Here's what I have so far:

```
class UserProfile(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    full_name = Column(Unicode(80))
    gender = Column(Enum(u'M',u'F','D', name='gender'), nullable=False)
    description = Column(Unicode(280))
    followed = relationship(Follow, backref="followers") 

class Follow(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'follow'

    follower_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'), primary_key=True)
    followee_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'), primary_key=True)
    status = Column(Enum(u'A',u'B', name=u'status'), default=u'A')
    created = Column(DateTime, default=func.now())
    followee = relationship(UserProfile, backref="follower")
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is already *almost* answered in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18854791/1547831). Here this is improved by having the advantages of a *many-to-many* made with a bare link table.

I'm not good in SQL and neither in SqlAlchemy but since I had this problem in mind for some longer time, I tried to find a solution that has both advantages: an association object with additional attributes and a *direct* association like with a bare link table (which doesn't provide an object on its own for the association). Stimulated by additional suggestions of the op the following seems quiet nice to me:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# coding: utf-8

import sqlalchemy as sqAl
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, relationship, backref
from sqlalchemy.ext.associationproxy import association_proxy

engine = sqAl.create_engine('sqlite:///m2m-w-a2.sqlite') #, echo=True)
metadata = sqAl.schema.MetaData(bind=engine)

Base = declarative_base(metadata)

class UserProfile(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'user'

  id            = sqAl.Column(sqAl.Integer, primary_key=True)
  full_name     = sqAl.Column(sqAl.Unicode(80))
  gender        = sqAl.Column(sqAl.Enum('M','F','D', name='gender'), default='D', nullable=False)
  description   = sqAl.Column(sqAl.Unicode(280))
  following     = association_proxy('followeds', 'followee')
  followed_by   = association_proxy('followers', 'follower')

  def follow(self, user, **kwargs):
    Follow(follower=self, followee=user, **kwargs)

  def __repr__(self):
    return 'UserProfile({})'.format(self.full_name)

class Follow(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'follow'

  followee_id   = sqAl.Column(sqAl.Integer, sqAl.ForeignKey('user.id'), primary_key=True)
  follower_id   = sqAl.Column(sqAl.Integer, sqAl.ForeignKey('user.id'), primary_key=True)
  status        = sqAl.Column(sqAl.Enum('A','B', name=u'status'), default=u'A')
  created       = sqAl.Column(sqAl.DateTime, default=sqAl.func.now())
  followee      = relationship(UserProfile, foreign_keys=followee_id, backref='followers')
  follower      = relationship(UserProfile, foreign_keys=follower_id, backref='followeds')

  def __init__(self, followee=None, follower=None, **kwargs):
    """necessary for creation by append()ing to the association proxy 'following'"""
    self.followee = followee
    self.follower = follower
    for kw,arg in kwargs.items():
      setattr(self, kw, arg)

Base.metadata.create_all(engine, checkfirst=True)
session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)()

def create_sample_data(sess):
  import random
  usernames, fstates, genders = ['User {}'.format(n) for n in range(4)], ('A', 'B'), ('M','F','D')
  profs = []
  for u in usernames:
    user = UserProfile(full_name=u, gender=random.choice(genders))
    profs.append(user)
    sess.add(user)

  for u in [profs[0], profs[3]]:
    for fu in profs:
      if u != fu:
        u.follow(fu, status=random.choice(fstates))

  profs[1].following.append(profs[3]) # doesn't work with followed_by

  sess.commit()

# uncomment the next line and run script once to create some sample data
# create_sample_data(session)

profs = session.query(UserProfile).all()

print(       '{} follows {}: {}'.format(profs[0], profs[3], profs[3] in profs[0].following))
print('{} is followed by {}: {}'.format(profs[0], profs[1], profs[1] in profs[0].followed_by))

for p in profs:
  print("User: {0}, following: {1}".format(
    p.full_name,  ", ".join([f.full_name for f in p.following])))
  for f in p.followeds:
    print(" " * 25 + "{0} follow.status: '{1}'"
          .format(f.followee.full_name, f.status))
  print("            followed_by: {1}".format(
    p.full_name,  ", ".join([f.full_name for f in p.followed_by])))
  for f in p.followers:
    print(" " * 25 + "{0} follow.status: '{1}'"
          .format(f.follower.full_name, f.status))
```

It seems indispensible to define two relations for the [Association Object](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/basic_relationships.html#association-object). The [association_proxy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html?highlight=association_proxy#api-documentation) method seems to be not ideally tailored for self-referential relations. The argument oder of the `Follow` constructor doesn't seem logical to me but works only this way (this is  explained [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html#simplifying-association-objects)).

In the book [Rick Copeland - Essential Sqlalchemy](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596516147.do) on page 117 you find the following note regarding the `secondary`-parameter to `relationship()`:

> Note that, if you are using SQLAlchemy’s ability to do M:N
>   relationships, the join table should *only* be used to join the two
>   tables together, not to store auxilliary properties. If you need to
>   use the intermediate join table to store addi- tional properties of
>   the relation, you should use two 1:N relations instead.

Sorry for that this is a little bit verbose but I like code that I can copy, paste, and execute directly. This works with Python 3.4 and SqlAlchemy 0.9 but likely also with other versions.

Comment: I have come across that post and found that it is most relevant to my question. However, I suppose I am more specifically looking for a solution that doesn't involve defining both relationships. I do have two follow up questions to your solution. First, wouldn't similar functionality be achievable via association proxies on either the "Follow" or "UserProfile" classes? Also, why is it necessary to explicitly define the joins (primaryjoin and secondaryjoin).

Comment: I'm yet thinking about it and I'm sure that there are several ways to do this better. -- I don't know how to disambiguate the assignment of `user.id -> follow.follower_id` resp. `user.id -> follow.followee_id` without explicitly defining primaryjoin/secondardjoin.

Comment: @AndrewBurnett Thank you for your hint regarding association proxies and of course for asking the initial question (I voted for it). It prevented me for hours to do the things I planned yesterday... - I removed the additional "direct" many-to-many `relation` and added a handy `follow` method.

Comment: It might be naive of me to ask, but why is it that you feel two relations are indispensable? Why not use backrefs to save the headache of manually keeping both sides of the relation in sync?

Comment: You can ignore my last comment; I hadn't yet read the excerpt from Copeland's text. I understand now that we are trying to avoid using M:N relations. I believe this is a fine way to execute my original problem. If you find a more elegant solution in the future, please keep me updated. Thank you for all of your help.

Comment: In order to make adding relationships from both sides (see your comment in code: *# doesn't work with followed_by*), you need to use [`creator`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html) parameter to `association_proxy` so that `SA` knows how to create `Follow` instances: `following = association_proxy('followeds', 'followee', creator=lambda followee: Follow(followee=followee)); followed_by = association_proxy('followers', 'follower', creator=lambda follower: Follow(followee=follower))`

Comment: @van Yes, thank you. For this example it would also work to only define the second (with fixed typo `followed_by = association_proxy('followers', 'follower', creator=lambda follower: Follow(follower=follower))`) but defining  both makes us independent of the argument order for the constructor of `Follow` and we can change the signature like `def __init__(self, follower=None, followee=None, **kwargs):` which feels more adequate.

Comment: @van Given the code above, how is it that constructor knows what values to use for both the "followee" and "follower" attributes given that the creator only provides a single, keyword argument?

Comment: @AndrewBurnett: it is *known* to any function call (including constructor) because a *keyword* argument has a *name* (unlike the *positional* argument). So it will pass values for named (keyword) arguments properly and use the default values for other arguments.

Comment: @van I suppose what I meant is that I don't understand how, when appending() to our following or followed_by association proxies, the constructor knows a value for the alternate attribute. Our creator function is only supplied a single argument and the constructor for the Follow class has default values of "None" for both the followee and follower attributes. When only a single argument is supplied via this creator, how is that a value is supplied for the alternate attribute (i.e. the "follower" when appending() to the "following" association proxy)?

Comment: @van Should the proxies not be: `following = association_proxy('followeds', 'followee', creator=lambda followee: Follow(follower=self, followee=followee))` and `followed_by = association_proxy('followers', 'follower', creator=lambda follower: Follow(follower=follower, followee=self))`

Comment: @AndrewBurnett According to the [docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html#simplifying-association-objects) `prof1.following.append(prof2)` is equivalent to `prof1.followeds.append(Follow(user2))` where in the `append`-method the `follower` *attribute* is "assigned" (the doc says *argument* but that seems not accurate the term to me). So, as I understand it, even if `self` had a valid (and right) value in the `creator` lambda it would be overwritten by the `append` method anyway.

Comment: @TNT: your assumption can be tested by providing another instance instead of `self`.... and thanks for replying to the questions of Andrew further...

Comment: @TNT Sorry, I overlooked that in the docs. Thank you so much for your help! This was my first SO question and I appreciate you guys for making it worthwhile.

Comment: This answer was just what I was looking for. It took me a little while to get my head around the follower/followee terminology, but I've managed to adapt it to my use case. Thanks!