# How to solve a sqlalchemy.exc.AmbiguousForeignKeysError in SQLalchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, foreign-keys, relationship

I am learning SQLalchemy, so I decided to make a small database with a few tables in order to understand the way it works. In the docs and tutorials it all seems so clear, but when I start coding, I get long error messages, and right now I am stuck with this one.

I am trying to create 3 related tables in a store application that manages repairs: repairs, contacts and products. A repair will always have a single product (the one being repaired), a costumer (the person who owns the product) and a supplier (the external company responsible for the warranty exchange or the repair). I had decided to have a single 'contacts' table to store both the suppliers and the costumers. But now I am getting a `sqlalchemy.exc.AmbiguousForeignKeysError`. I have been reading the "relationships" section in the docs, but no idea about this message.

Here is my sample code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.6
# encoding: utf-8
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey, MetaData
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, backref
from random import choice

Base = declarative_base()


class Contact(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'contact'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)


class Product(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'product'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    product_descr = Column(String, nullable=False)


class Repair(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'repair'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    costumer_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('contact.id'))
    costumer = relationship("Contact", backref=backref('repair', uselist=True))
    product_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('product.id'))
    product = relationship("Product", backref=backref("repair", uselist=True))
    supplier_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('contact.id'))
    supplier = relationship("Contact", backref=backref("repair", uselist=True))


def init_database():
    engine = create_engine('sqlite+pysqlite://')
    session = sessionmaker()
    session.configure(bind=engine)
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)


def test_populate():
    engine = create_engine('sqlite+pysqlite://')
    session = sessionmaker()
    session.configure(bind=engine)
    s = session()

    names = ("Joseph", "Mark", "Mary", "Sophie", "Steven", "Joan")
    for i in range(30):
        name = f"{choice(names)}"
        contact = Contact(name=name)
        s.add(contact)

    s.commit()

    for i in range(50):
        descr = f"Sample Product number {str(i)}"
        pn = "NPKPN662" + str(i)
        product = product(product_descr=descr, part_number=pn)
        s.add(product)

    s.commit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    init_database()
    test_populate()
    print_database()
```

When I run the code above, I get this long error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py", line 2069, in _determine_joins
    consider_as_foreign_keys=consider_as_foreign_keys
  File "<string>", line 2, in join_condition
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/selectable.py", line 965, in _join_condition
    a, b, constraints, consider_as_foreign_keys)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/selectable.py", line 1055, in _joincond_trim_constraints
    "join explicitly." % (a.description, b.description))
sqlalchemy.exc.AmbiguousForeignKeysError: Can't determine join between 'repair' and 'contact'; tables have more than one foreign key constraint relationship between them. Please specify the 'onclause' of this join explicitly.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "teste.py", line 68, in <module>
    test_populate()
  File "teste.py", line 52, in test_populate
    contact = Contact(name=name)
  File "<string>", line 2, in __init__
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/instrumentation.py", line 347, in _new_state_if_none
    state = self._state_constructor(instance, self)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 754, in __get__
    obj.__dict__[self.__name__] = result = self.fget(obj)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/instrumentation.py", line 177, in _state_constructor
    self.dispatch.first_init(self, self.class_)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/event/attr.py", line 256, in __call__
    fn(*args, **kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 2954, in _event_on_first_init
    configure_mappers()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 2850, in configure_mappers
    mapper._post_configure_properties()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 1765, in _post_configure_properties
    prop.init()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/interfaces.py", line 183, in init
    self.do_init()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py", line 1653, in do_init
    self._setup_join_conditions()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py", line 1728, in _setup_join_conditions
    can_be_synced_fn=self._columns_are_mapped
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py", line 1986, in __init__
    self._determine_joins()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py", line 2113, in _determine_joins
    % self.prop)
sqlalchemy.exc.AmbiguousForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship Repair.costumer - there are multiple foreign key paths linking the tables.  Specify the 'foreign_keys' argument, providing a list of those columns which should be counted as containing a foreign key reference to the parent table.
```

Comment: `Repair` has 2 foreign keys referencing `Contact`, and so the relationships cannot know which one to use, so indicate that with the `foreign_keys=` argument. Both relationship attributes are trying to create a backref called "repairs", so that's also going to be problematic.

Comment: Where should I put the foreign_keys argument? Actually I still don’t understand very well the backref thing. I am trying to keep a way to get the repairs that are related to a given contact. Should I split the contact table in two separate tables?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22355890/sqlalchemy-multiple-foreign-keys-to-the-same-primary-id-in-another-table, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18807322/sqlalchemy-foreign-key-relationship-attributes

Comment: Pass [`foreign_keys=...`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship.params.foreign_keys) to the `relationship()` constructs. For example `supplier = relationship("Contact", foreign_keys=[supplier_id], ...)`. Related part from the docs: ["Handling Multiple Join Paths"](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/join_conditions.html#handling-multiple-join-paths)